# Is this the first time Sarah Jane has got in-universe closure?

Tags: doctor-who, the-sarah-jane-adventures

This short, written by Russell T. Davies, recently appeared on the Doctor Who Youtube channel:

It recounts the funeral of Sarah Jane Smith, with appearances by several characters (their actors evidently self-isolating at home IRL) from *Doctor Who* and *The Sarah Jane Adventures*. Of course I know Elisabeth Sladen passed away and so *The Sarah Jane Adventures* never continued, but as far as I know her character in the show never got even an off-screen death like the Brigadier: she simply didn't appear again in *Doctor Who*, and *The Sarah Jane Adventures* didn't continue.

**Is this Youtube video the first time Sarah Jane's death has been confirmed in-universe, and the first time her character got any kind of "closure"?** Canonicity in the Whoniverse is of course a huge can of worms, but I think we can count this as at least some level of canon, being written by RTD and starring many characters played by their original actors from the show. Obviously I don't count fanfiction written by random fans on the internet, but has there been anything before at *any* level of "canonicity" which tied up Sarah Jane's story at all?

Comment: She was very much alive at the age of 120+ in the comic Ground Zero; https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Ground_Zero_(comic_story)